# How to share data between projects (server and client)

Tags: rust

I have web server and client with following structure:

```
├── server
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── client
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
```

How can i share between them some functions like:

```
pub fn todo() -> i32 {
    2
}
```

Variables that will be different based on build arguments.

And how to make it work if server and client will be build at the same time during development?

Comment: Why not make a shared library?

Comment: @tadman it's get compiled two times and i think there will be problems when you build server and client at the same time with different arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804503/

Comment: You could make it a separate crate that both can use independently if you're getting friction there.

Comment: @tadman i would appreciate simple example

Comment: Another directory with a `Cargo.toml` file in it is another dependency, and you can reference this in the other crates using `path = "../lib"` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

A language-independent approach, is to put both of the projects in one workspace, where each file can be owned by multiple projects. With one workspace, you can also make a third project, a library, that both of the other projects have a dependency on, so that this library is always compiled before use by the other projects. You can also move this library out of the workspace, but then you give yourself more job, in compiling and linking. How you do this, is IDE specific. I haven’t done any programming in Rust, so I’m unaware of other solutions specific to Rust, or Rust IDEs.